# Do local variables get collected after method is done running

Tags: java, variables, garbage-collection

For example

```
public void doSomething() {
   Dog smallDog = new Dog();
   smallDog.bark();
}
```

will the dog object be collected after this method is run?

Comment: When else would the Dog instance be collected except AFTER it was created? :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can become *eligible* to be collected when the method returns.  When garbage collection actually happens is some unknown time in the future.

It is impossible to tell for sure without seeing the implementation of bark().

If this is your bark:

```
public void bark() {
   BarkListeners.callBack(this);
}

public class BarkListeners {
  private static final List<Dog> barkers = new ArrayList<Dog>();

  public static void callBack(Dog dog) {
    barkers.add(dog);
  }
}
```

Then no, it won't be getting garbage collected!

Comment: great explanation. So it would only be collected if there are no more calls towards it.

Comment: There's one more possibility - *that it won't even need garbage collecting*. The JIT can perform escape analysis, which checks if a number of preconditions are fulfilled (no references to the object escape outside the local context, it doesn't have a finalizer, possibly more). If these preconditions are met, the object can be allocated on the stack = no GC needed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply no. I mean, the timing does not have to be like that.

All Java Objects are allocated in the heap and collected by the GarbageCollector. And GarbageCollector runs in background, with almost no constraint on when to perform actual garbage collection.

Comment: And the GarbageCollectorruns when the JVM wishes.

Comment: s/when /when *and if* /.  There's no guarantee GC will run at all.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it isn't possible to give and answer because we haven't seen the implementation for `Dog#bark()`.

Generally, the answer is YES, the `Dog` instance will be collected AFTER the method is run, it just isn't possible to know exactly when. The reason for this is that unless the `bark` method shares the reference to the `Dog` object with another object, the particular instance of `Dog` will no longer be reachable. The next time the Garbage Collector runs, it will determine that `Dog` is not reachable and collect the heap space that was used to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on reach ability of the object. If object is not reachable then it is eligilble for GC. When to GC is dependent on JVM implementation. [Truth About Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) provides a good explanation on how the garbage collection process works. To summarize:

> An Object becomes eligible for Garbage collection if its not reachable from any live threads or any static refrences. It (the Garbage Collector) will only trigger if JVM thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java heap size.

Therefore you shouldn't make assumptions on when any object will be garbage collected.